# poi how to get a font animation?

Tags: animation, apache-poi

How to use poi to get an animation, this animation is added to a paragraph of text.
The class for text processing is XSLFShape and several classes that inherit this class, all of which have no relevant methods to deal with。

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? And what do you want to do with that information? It is true that `apache poi` does not have methods to get timing settings of the slides in `XSLF` until now. But of course those settings are in slide's XML and thus are able to get too. But what exactly and why?

Comment: i want to get shadow
i want to get transparency or Alpha
i wang to get animation, like fly into

The most important thing is how to get xml? What does xml mean? Are there relevant documents?

Can i use chinese？

我想获取一个动画效果，如 飞入，飞出，还有透明度，形状选项等，最重要的，xml怎么获取呢？获取到xml后，这个xml的字段意思是啥？是否有文档呢？

Comment: As it is now, the question is too broad to be answered here. `Apache poi` does not provide direct access to slide animation in `XSLF`. If you want to know how to get the related `XML` and where to find information about that `XML` then please ask that. And no, you cannot use Chinese language here. Language here is English only.

Comment: Do you know where to get information about xml related documents

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/understanding-the-open-xml-file-formats -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-presentationml-documents -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/structure-of-a-presentationml-document -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.presentation.slide?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=openxml-2.8.1 -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.presentation.timing?view=openxml-2.8.1